# GUI with Tkinter, failed to read the image from one function to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-button

**Summary of problem:** I am implementing GUI using tkinter for the image matching task in which I have written some code. After executing that code it generates the GUI in which on clicking first button I upload first “image1” then on clicking second button I upload second “image2”. Now I need to perform image matching operations on those both uploaded image, so I created third button but when I click the third button to match the features between those two images I get an error which is mentioned below. I think the third button is not able to read those two uploaded images which are from two different functions or maybe I am passing wrong variable. Any kind of suggestions or help or solution to this problem will be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import numpy as np
import cv2

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1300x600")
root.minsize(1299,599)
root.maxsize(1300,600)
root.title("Examine GUI")

img1_resized = None
img2_resized = None

def upload_file1():
    global img1_resized
    f_types = [("all files", "*.*"), ('png Files', '*.png'), ('Jpg Files', '*.jpg')]
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = f_types)
    img1 = Image.open(filename)
    img1_resized = img1.resize((300,150)) 
    img1_f = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1_resized)
    l2 = Label(root, image=img1_f)
    l2.image = img1_f # keep a reference to avoid disappearing of image
    l2.grid(row=1,column=0)
    
b1 = Button(root, text = 'Browse to Select Image1', bg = 'white', fg = 'black',
            font = 'comicsansms 10 bold', borderwidth = 5, relief = SUNKEN, command = lambda:upload_file1())
b1.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=1)

def upload_file2():
    global img2_resized
    f_types = [("all files", "*.*"), ('png Files', '*.png'), ('Jpg Files', '*.jpg')]
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = f_types)
    img2 = Image.open(filename)
    img2_resized = img2.resize((300,150)) 
    img2_f = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2_resized)
    l3 = Label(root, image=img2_f)
    l3.image = img2_f
    l3.grid(row=1,column=1)
    
b2 = Button(root, text = 'Browse to Select Image2', bg = 'white', fg = 'black',
            font = 'comicsansms 10 bold', borderwidth = 5, relief = SUNKEN, command = lambda:upload_file2())
b2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=1)    

def process_match():
    # Image Filtering/Noise Removal
    bif = cv2.bilateralFilter(img1_resized,9,75,75)
    bif2 = cv2.bilateralFilter(img2_resized,9,75,75)
    # Grayscale Conversion 
    img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(bif, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(bif2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # ORB Implementation For Feature Extraction
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kp1, desc1 = orb.detectAndCompute(erosion, None)
    kp2, desc2 = orb.detectAndCompute(erosion2, None)
    # Feature Matching Using Brute-Force Matcher
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    # Performing Feature Matching 
    featurematches = bf.match(desc1, desc2)
    matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(img1_resized, kp1, img2_resized, kp2, featurematches, None, flags = 2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    img3_f = ImageTk.PhotoImage(matching_result)
    l4 = Label(root, image=img3_f)
    l4.image = img3_f
    l4.grid(row=1,column=2)

b3 = Button(root, text = 'Initiate Image Matching Process', bg = 'white', fg = 'black',
            font = 'comicsansms 10 bold', borderwidth = 5, relief = SUNKEN, command = lambda:process_match())
b3.grid(row=2,column=2,pady=1)    

b5 = Button(root, text = 'Exit', bg = 'white', fg = 'black',
            font = 'comicsansms 10 bold', borderwidth = 5, relief = SUNKEN, command = root.destroy)
b5.grid(row=5,column=0,pady=1)    

root.mainloop()
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ankitpc\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17112\2128255387.py", line 74, in <lambda>
    font = 'comicsansms 10 bold', borderwidth = 5, relief = SUNKEN, command = lambda:process_match())
  File "C:\Users\ankitpc\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17112\2128255387.py", line 50, in process_match
    bif = cv2.bilateralFilter(img1_resized,9,75,75)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'bilateralFilter'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Comment: You need to use `img = cv2.imread(img1_resized)` before using the filter. The data is completely different from `Image.open` therefore your code crash.

Comment: try `cv2.bilateralFilter(np.asarray(img1_resized),9,75,75)`same for bif2 - Opencv just uses  numpy matrizes Image gives you an object which is fairly different from numpy

Comment: @jack error is resolved, thanks. But further in the code `matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(img1_resized, kp1, img2_resized, kp2, featurematches, None, flags = 2)` when I pass the image to draw the matches on them an error occurred. `cv2.error:OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'drawMatches'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img1 is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img1'
>  - drawMatches() missing required argument 'matchesThickness' (pos 7)
>  - drawMatches() missing required argument 'matchesThickness' (pos 7)
`

Comment: @Truthin7 It's the same error, maybe Image provides the functionality to resize the Image but numpy does not it would crop it. So after the resizing is done convert you Image Object to an numpy array as before

Comment: @jack I have done that but it shows `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`